# What are the chances of each gumball dropping?

Tags: sonic-3-and-knuckles, sonic-3

In Sonic 3 (and by extension, Sonic 3 & Knuckles) there is a Gumball-dispenser bonus stage which dispenses different power-ups, including the various shields, rings, extra lives and a few other arena-specific ones, such as the rubber/bounce balls.

[image: Gumball machine dispensing an electric shield]

You can watch the bonus stage in action here:

What are the chances that the gumball machine dispenses one type of ball over another? Are they uniformly released, or does say, a Bubble shield appear more often then an extra life?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you touch the handle, the game rolls a random chance from this list:

- Bumper (Black): 4 out of 16
- Ring (Grey): 2 out of 16
- Clear (Nothing): 2 out of 16
- Water Shield (Blue) : 2 out of 16
- Flame Shield (Red): 2 out of 16
- Electric Shield (Orange): 2 out of 16
- Rep (Green): 1 out of 16
- 1UP (Pink): 1 out of 16

*source for this list is http://hcstealth.tumblr.com/post/100311283757/sonic-3-knuckles-20th-anniversary*

The Rep chances are unique in that if the game rolls a Rep while the bottom springs are still active, the game will re-roll that particular chance using a different list:

- Black (Bumper): 8 out of 16
- Clear (Nothing): 4 out of 16
- Ring (Grey): 3 out of 16
- 1UP (Pink): 1 out of 16

The game also checks the result of the roll against its last roll, and if the result would be the same, it "flips a coin" on whether or not the result is re-rolled.